# How to extract tuples from a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following list in Haskell

```
[
    [("Name", "Alice"), ("Age", "21")],
    [("Name", "Bob"), ("Age", "22")],
    [("Name", "Eve"), ("Age", "20")]
]
```

How can I get a list `[...]` of the Ages like this:

`[("Age", "21"), ("Age", "22"), ("Age", "20")]`

I think it can be done using set comprehension but Im not sure.

Comment: If you want to extract tuples from this specific list, you akready have the answer. If you need to work with general lists, state general requirements. You msy want to extract the second entry from each list, or entries that have "Age" in them, or something else.

Comment: @Franky yeah you are right, I changed `(String, Int)` to `(String, String)`

Comment: Are you looking for something more complicated than `map (!! 1)`?

Comment: @ChrisMartin I could do that, but I was looking for a more generic approach. Namely by specifying the "field" name I wanted. In this case "age"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'll give you an answer, but first, note that the type of the list that you have provided us is not allowed....

The first type in each list has type `(String, String)`, the second has type `Num a=>(String, a)`.  Haskell doesn't allow mixed lists.

That being said, once you fix this (for instance, changing the age tuple to `("age", "2")`), you have a few choices:

---

If you always want the value in the tuple starting with "Age" can use the following

```
map (lookup "Age") $ theList
```

This almost works, but will return type `[Maybe String]`.  You can remove the `Just` by using `fromJust`, but be careful, this will crash the program if it doesn't exist.  A cleaner approach would be to use `fromMaybe`, which lets you fill in a default value in case of `Nothing`.

```
map (fromMaybe "ageless" . lookup "Age") $ theList
```

---

If you always want the second value in the list, use

```
map (snd . tail) $ theList
```

Likewise, the program will crash if any list doesn't have two items.

There are safe versions of `tail` in the "safe" package (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.3/docs/Safe.html).  For instance, you can use

```
map (snd . tailDef ("", "Ageless")) $ theList
```

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way I can think of doing it would so:

```
getAges :: [[a]] -> [a]
getAges = map (!! 1)
```

This is just a function which retrieves the second element of each sublist within the first list. That should work in this particular case, but if you want to match the tuples with the "Name" tag, that's more difficult:

```
getAges :: [[a]] -> [a]
getAges list = do
        person <- list
        tags <- person
        get' tags
    where get' (tag,val) | tag == "Age" = return (tag,val)
                         | otherwise    = fail "Not age tag"
```

This will extract the "Age" tuples from a nested array, without a touch of `Maybe`!